# Why does discord.py not allow me to add reactions?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So this is what I currently have, except that it doesn't work. It gives me the following error:

```
Ignoring exception in command suggestion:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 79, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/Discord bot/main.py", line 57, in suggestion   
await bot.add_reaction(message, ":yes:614465426788843551")
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'
```

and then I get another error after that with the same thing, but for `:no:`. Could you guys help?

Code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def suggestion(message):
    await bot.add_reaction(message, ":yes:614465426788843551")
    await bot.add_reaction(message, ":no:614465426381996033")
    print('test done')
```

Comment: *You must have the `read_message_history` permission to use this. If nobody else has reacted to the message using this emoji, the `add_reactions` permission is required.*

Comment: i've done that. it still gives the error

Comment: There's an `AttributeError` because that `Bot` method doesn't exist anymore. The issue has nothing to do with permissions.

Answer (score -1):

You're using syntax from a version of discord.py, v0.16, that isn't supported anymore.
See [the guide for migrating to v1](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html), specifically the [Models are Stateful section](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#models-are-stateful).
You should use [`Message.add_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.add_reaction) rather than `Bot.add_reaction`.